# OrdinalIgnoreCase is not working with dynamic array in c#

Tags: c#, string, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to ignore case of string while compare string using `contains` but somehow I am getting syntax error.

```
List<string> name1 = new List<string>();
public void ClickOnSeeAllConnection()
{              
    for (int i =0; i <=10; i++)
    {
        name1.Add(driver.FindElement(
            By.XPath("(//span[@class='name actor-name'])[" + i + "]")).Text + "," + 
            driver.FindElement(
              By.XPath("(//p[contains(@class,'subline-level-1')])[" 
                       + i + "]")).Text)             
    }

    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
    {
        if (name1[j].Contains(
               ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("Name"),
               StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {
               //do something
        }
    }    
}
```

Above seems fine if I try with single string but when it comes to array it is not working. It shows me `argumentNullException`.

[image]

Comment: But `name` appears empty given your example code.

Comment: There are no dynamic arrays in this code. Just a List<string>. If there's no match it's because the ordinal values of the strings *don't* match. Post a sample that actually reproduces the problem. Or, as Andrew metnioned, there are no strings to match in the first place

Comment: And `counter` never increments.

Comment: Yes I just want know about what is wrong. Name has already values.

Comment: The code, as is, is not throwing `argumentNullException`. It can't be. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @HelpingHands the problem is that your code is wrong and couldn't even run. It should throw because the `name` is empty. There are no strings to match. Either you didn't try debugging or this isn't the *actual* code.

Comment: @HelpingHands if you get an ArgumentNullException it's because you passed a null *somewhere*. Debug the application and check the values when the exception is thrown. If you want help, post the *actual* code and the full exception including its call stack. You can get it with `Exception.ToString()`

Comment: I updated code.

Comment: Do not dump a large part of your code here - go to File|NewProject and create a small, clear and compact demonstration of the issue. That is a [mcve]

Comment: you are making an assumption not only that `name` has had anything added to it, but that `name` has exactly 10 elements.  you simply need to check that name has anything in it first.

Comment: That's not throwing an argument null exception, it's telling you that the `Contains` method can throw that if you pass in a null argument. It's also telling you that `Contains` doesn't accept a `StringComparison` enum as a second parameter.

Comment: Your code formatting is messy and it needed tidying for us to follow it. So I tidied it. In doing so I see you are missing a ; in your code. See? Sometimes it is better to break your code down that use huge daisy chains because anything in the chain might be null. Have you put your code in try / catch blocks? Have you debugged and traced it step by step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure `name` has stuff in it, and rather than assuming 10 elements just iterate over its contents.  As to why name is either empty or has less than 10 elements in it, that's a problem with the code that adds elements to name.

```
if ((name != null) && (name.Any())
{
    foreach(string thisName in name)
    {
        var stringToSearch = ConfigurationManager
            .AppSettings.Get("Name");
        //Contains doesn't work with ignore case option...
        //if (thisName.Contains(stringToSearch, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))

        //.indexOf does though... So this works
        if (thisName.IndexOf(stringToSearch,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) 
        {
               //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I have issue with syntax. Data is fine. Can you please look , I have updated questions with screenshot.

Comment: @HelpingHands I didn't even check that...But I've edited the answer now. You could Upper/lowercase both strings, but .IndexOf lets you specify OrdinalIgnoreCase so just use that.  Note that this may not work with accented characters so you may need to take account of different culture settings depending on your specific use case...

Answer (score 1):

Check the documentation for [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) it doesn't take two arguments in the way you're expecting, only a string:

> Returns a value indicating whether a specified substring occurs within this string.
>
> **Syntax**

```
public bool Contains(
    string value
)
```

> **Parameters**
> `value`
> Type: `System.String`
> The string to seek.

The document then goes on to list a custom extension method you can use to extend Contains to take the string comparison enum you're attempting to use:

```
using System;

public static class StringExtensions
{
   public static bool Contains(this String str, String substring, 
                               StringComparison comp)
   {                            
      if (substring == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException("substring", 
                                         "substring cannot be null.");
      else if (! Enum.IsDefined(typeof(StringComparison), comp))
         throw new ArgumentException("comp is not a member of StringComparison",
                                     "comp");

      return str.IndexOf(substring, comp) >= 0;                      
   }
}
```